# ListView of Cards with no margin still shows background between Cards

Tags: flutter

Consider the following example:

```
Widget build() => ListView(children: [
    Card(
        child: ListTile(title: Text("Hello")),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0)),
    Card(
        child: ListTile(title: Text("Hello")),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0))
  ]);
```

When this gets rendered on black background in a ListView and I scroll up and down, I see some black line randomly appearing between the Cards.

I guess that's due to rounding errors. Is there a way to make the Cards slightly overlap so that the glitch doesn't show up?

UPDATE:

`elevation: 0.0` does not help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `elevation: 0` on the Cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a widget that pretends to be bigger/smaller than it is.

I wrap the `Card` into that with: `AdjustSizeWidget(deltaSize: Size(0.0, -1.0), child: Card(...))`.

This way, the adjacent cards will overlap and the seam disappears.

Here's the code:

```
///
/// A widget that pretends to be bigger or smaller than it is.
///
class AdjustSizeWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const AdjustSizeWidget({Widget child, this.deltaSize}) : super(child: child);

  final Size deltaSize;

  @override
  _RenderAdjustSizeWidget createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return _RenderAdjustSizeWidget(deltaSize);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, covariant _RenderAdjustSizeWidget renderObject) {
    super.updateRenderObject(context, renderObject);
    if (deltaSize != renderObject.deltaSize) {
      renderObject.deltaSize = deltaSize;
      renderObject.markNeedsLayout();
    }
  }
}

class _RenderAdjustSizeWidget extends RenderProxyBox {
  _RenderAdjustSizeWidget(this.deltaSize);

  Size deltaSize;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();
    size = Size(math.max(size.width + deltaSize.width, 0),
        math.max(size.height + deltaSize.height, 0));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be some kind of ways to make them overlap (for example using the `Stack` widget) but this should not be considered since there are easier ways. The implementation of the `Card` widget is fairly simple and small, nothing too special it does so you can easily create your own widget to create the behaviour you want! I present you one example which would produce the output you probably seek:

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Hello'),                 
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Hello'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

I used the `Card` widget as the styled container and used a `Column` widget which does not scroll and can have multiple widgets which will be rendered vertically with the `MainAxisAlignment.start` property to make the content align to the left.

**EDIT**

Variant with a `SliverList` inside a `CustomScrollView`:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      title: Text('Title'),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Card(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('Hello'),
                );
              }, childCount: 5),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: The underlying usecase is a SliverList with an infinite/long list of Cards, this is why I cannot use your approach.

Comment: CustomScrollView inside CustomScrollView? Will this cause issues?

Comment: If you experience any kind of scrolling issues because the inner CustomScrollView consumes the user scroll, you can simply set NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() as the physic property of the list - but in my example it did not cause any trouble so far

Comment: Now I remember, the main problem is that my list is (almost) infinite. A SliverToBoxAdapter needs a definite size. So that might not work...